# Sed replace blocks of text from 2 files

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed

I have 2 files: oldfile and newfile which are similar in structure, they only contain minor changes

I need to replace a block of text from newfile with a block from the oldfile (as a bash script)

In oldfile I have:

... text

```
#######################################################################
# LDAP Settings
LDAPUrl = ldap://xxx
LDAPSearchBase = CN=Users,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=xx
LDAPSearchSecondary = ***
LDAPSearchFilter = cn=xxx
LDAPUser = CN=***,CN=Users,DC=xx,DC=xxx,DC=xx
LDAPPassword = ***
LDAPAuthenticateServer = ldap://test:389
ProsourceKey = ****

#######################################################################
```

... other text

newfile is identical only parameters values are changed.

I used sed the get this output from the oldfile like this:
getldap=`sed -n '/^# LDAP Settings$/,/^$/p' oldfile > ldap.tmp` (it stores it in ldap.tmp)

used the delimiters: # LDAP Settings and the empty line that contains a space

Now I want to insert that output into newfile and replace the existing similar text.

Comment: what is your question or problem then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right tool for the right job, here awk will suite your requirements much better than sed.

This awk should work:

```
awk -F '[= ]+' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1' oldfile newfile
```

**Update: To restrict replacements to `# LDAP Settings` only you can do:**

```
awk -F '[= ]+' 'FNR==NR && /^# LDAP Settings$/{r=1;next} FNR==NR && r && /^$/{r=0;next} 
   r && FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} FNR!=NR{if($1 in a)$0=a[$1];print}' oldfile newfile
```

**Explanation:**

This awk command can be divided into 2 sections:

```
-F '[= ]+' - Use field separator = or space or both
FNR == NR - First file is being processed
FNR != NR - Second file is being processed
FNR == NR && /^# LDAP Settings$/ - In 1st file if # LDAP Settings is found set r=1
r && FNR==NR - a[$1]=$0 - In 1st file if r=1 then
a[$1]=$0 - Store 1st field as key in array a and $0 (whole line) as value
FNR==NR && r && /^$/ - In 1st file if r=1 and empty line found then set r=0

FNR!=NR{if($1 in a)$0=a[$1];print} In 2nd file if $1 exists in a then set whole line as 
                                   value of array a. Then print the whole line
```

Comment: Sorry but this does not seem to work, if I understand correctly this should replace all values after [= ] but I only want that certain block, there are other values that I don't want to be replaced. Also when I run it, it does nothing in changes to the newfile

Comment: Post a sample of newfile. Also awk doesn't change the newfile, you need to redirect the output to a separate file and then move it back to newfile e.g `awk -F '[= ]+' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next} $1 in a{$0=a[$1]}1' oldfile newfile > _temp && mv _temp newfile`

Comment: Ok this does work to some extend: it replaces successfully the block but there are other lines with = and in the end I get a lot of junk data in the newfile

Comment: for ex:#######################################################################
#       production/testing time - ImporterEngineInitialisation=on
#       production/testing time - ImporterEngineInitialisation=on
#       production/testing time - ImporterEngineInitialisation=on
#       production/testing time - ImporterEngineInitialisation=on
#       production/testing time - ImporterEngineInitialisation=on
CatalogImporterEngineInitialisation=on

#######################################################################
#       production/testing time - ImporterEngineInitialisation=on

Comment: Is it same to assume to start replacement at `# LDAP Settings` and end at an empty line?

Comment: It works but messes up other content in the file, here I attached the actual oldfile http://pastebin.com/5TGCEeur

Comment: No, its still no good, it seems to put 2 instances of the file in newfile

Comment: Yes now it works fine, thanks. Can you elaborate a bit about the command? It seems very complex to understand, at least for a beginner. It would be nice if I could learn to modify it myself for other tasks for example to replace another block of code between other delimiters.

Comment: Yes adding explanation in a bit.

Comment: Added some explanation. It might not be very good and please go through an online awk tutorial for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The following `sed` command will replace the LDAP Settings section with the contents of ldap.tmp:

```
sed '/^# LDAP Settings$/,/^$/ {//!d}; /^# LDAP Settings$/r ldap.tmp' newfile
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, only problem is that I get 2 # LDAP Settings lines

Comment: can you remove the LDAP Settings line from ldap.tmp?

Comment: I`m not sure how to do that, if I use another delimiter like LDAPUrl = , then I don't have any output in my tmp file

Comment: The easiest way is to use `tail` to remove the first line when creating ldap.tmp like this: `sed -n '/^# LDAP Settings$/,/^$/p' file | tail -n +2  > ldap.tmp`