# how to replace a block of text from a file with a block of text from another file using shell (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace a block of text from **file_to_change.xml** with the entire content of **changes.xml**, which is a tag of the main file with a minor change.

This is the content of file_to_change.xml:

```xml
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <age>12</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Carlos</name>
        <age>28</age>
    </client>
</clients>
```

And this is the content of changes.xml:

```xml
    <client>
        <name>Carlita</name>
        <age>17</age>
    </client>
```

And this is the content of an auxiliary file that contains the line i want to change:

```xml
    <client>
        <name>Carlos</name>
        <age>28</age>
    </client>
```

The great difference between the solution i'm looking for from the one explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829753/sed-replace-blocks-of-text-from-2-files) is that the files are not entirely equal. It is also important to say that the environment i'm working at do not allow me to use external tools, and for that reason i'm trying to find a "core" solution, using sed, awk, etc.

This is the command i was trying to use:

```
sed -i -e '1r changes.xml' -e '1,/r aux.xml/d' file_to_change.xml
```

I'm expecting that the file_to_change.xml look like this:

```xml
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <age>12</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Carlita</name>
        <age>17</age>
    </client>
</clients>
```

Comment: You named both the files `file_to_change.xml`. One of them should be `changes.xml`.

Comment: Why Carlos have two different ages from input and auxiliary file ?

Comment: That was another mistyping, since it works as a way to identify the line to be change, they must be identical.

Comment: please update the question to show the (correct) expected result

Comment: Does the auxiliary file exactly contains a part of file_to_change? I mean, the indentation, etc...

Comment: @Fravadona yeah, it's a slice of the main xml (that's why they are identical), such as the one you helped me built [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75148375/get-the-lines-of-a-file-between-two-matching-patterns-which-contains-a-specific)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pure bash?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

file=$( < file_to_change.xml )
search=$( < aux.xml )
replacement=$( < changes.xml )

printf '%s\n' "${file/"$search"/$replacement}"
```

```xml
<clients>
    <client>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>18</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Alice</name>
        <age>12</age>
    </client>
    <client>
        <name>Carlita</name>
        <age>17</age>
    </client>
</clients>
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly Fravadona. I didn't know that printf could be used for such purposes. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
JKL
MNO
```

and `file_detect.txt` be

```
GHI
JKL
```

and `file_replacement.txt` be

```
123
456
789
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}FILENAME=="file_replacement.txt"{repl=$0;next}FILENAME=="file_detect.txt"{find=$0;next}{place=index($0,find);print substr($0,1,place-1) repl substr($0,place+length(find))}' file_replacement.txt file_detect.txt file.txt
```

gives output

```
ABC
DEF
123
456
789
MNO
```

**Disclaimer**: this solution assumes you have never blank lines in any of your files, if this does not hold change `RS` to any value which does not exist in any of files involved.

Explanation: firstly I inform GNU `AWK` that blank lines are to be considered row separators using `RS` set to empty string, aim there is to make GNU `AWK` consider whole file as big single line. Then when I encounter file named `file_replacement.txt` I simply store its' content into variable named `repl` and instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` line, so no other action is undertaken, similarly content of `file_detect.txt` are stored in variable named `find`. Then I use [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) following way, first `index` to detect where part to be replace is located, then I use `substr` to get part before part to be replaced `substr($0,1,place-1)` and part after part to be replaced `substr($0,place+length(find)` and then `print` them concatenated using `repl`.

**Warning**: this solution assumes there is exactly one `file_detect.txt` inside `file.txt`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Daweo, thanks for your explanation. I tried this solution out and also worked as intended, though i couldn't make this awk function to support variables within its command.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ez 's/.*/echo -n "@@@&@@@" | cat fileToSearch - fileReplacement/e
         s/^(.*)@@@(.*)\1(.*)@@@(.*)/\2\4\3/' file
```